# Not working addPersistentPreferredActivity() method of DevicePolicyManager

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

I am using addPersistentPreferredActivity() method of DevicePolicyManager but its not working.

I made Google Nexus 5.0 android device as device owner using dpm command and after that I used above method to make my application's activity as HomeActivity but its not working.

Below is the piece of code which I am using:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
devicePolicyManager.addPersistentPreferredActivity(demoDeviceAdmin,filter,new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),LauncherActivity.class));
```

Can anyone help me to sort out this issue?

Comment: is there any error in the log file?

Comment: No, There is no error in log file.

Comment: It seems it's broken on 5.0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504495/addpersistentpreferredactivity-on-api21 Have you tried on 5.1 or 6.0? /Marek Pola, Sony Mobile.

Comment: Yes, I am trying on Google Nexus with 5.1.1 OS version

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to add this in your activity manifest:

```android
<intent-filter>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```